# Attach file to list in Sandbox Webpart

Tags: file-upload, sharepoint-2010, sandbox-solution

I am trying to create a custom control for updating a List on a Sharepoint site that only allows Sandbox Solutions to be added.

I've read a few threads on uploading attachments, but they all seem to involve doing it from the server machine (Using a file stream to read a local file).

Is it not possible to use Javascript or something to pass a file through to a Sandbox'd webpart??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it seems, is no. You cannot.